# Read trace file from android APP

Tags: android, trace, systrace

I am trying to read content of /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace file from my code but i am unable to do so.I have tried mounting using
mount -o rw,remount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
and have also done chmod -R 777 /sys/kernel/debug

```
          File myFile = new File("/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace");
    FileInputStream fIn = null;
    try {
        fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow;
    try {
        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), aDataRow, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            t.setText(aDataRow);
            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You want to get the system logs or something else?

Comment: Are you able to run systrace at all?  Some devices (and, I think, the AOSP emulator) ship with systrace disabled in the kernel.  What device and version of Android are you using?

Comment: Systrace is enabled on the device and I am able to get html file from systrace

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "su" command in your program.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace" });
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```